# How can I pass a JS result into a Twig template?

Tags: templating, javascript

I've got a frontend form which queries the openstates.org API to return a given set of data objects.

Those objects also exist in Craft as entries, and the API data includes a field that serves as a unique ID for the Craft entries - how can I pass those unique IDs back to the Craft template to retrieve the corresponding entries?

Comment: You could add them as query string to the URL. When rendering the page, you can tan check the query strign to see which ones you'd have to display...

Comment: Thanks, Michael - that worked perfectly. I wound up combining it with the [sample code from this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/search-contact-person-plugin-via-ajax).

Comment: Perhaps add your working combination as answer? That way people in the future can directly see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Michael's suggestion above, with some help from [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/search-contact-person-plugin-via-ajax), I passed the results from the API call back to a craft template as query params, so it looked like this (simplified):

```
{% if craft.request.isAjax %}
    {% set myReps = craft.request.getParam('personId') %}
    {% set myIds = myReps | split(',') %}
    {% for myId in myIds %}
        {% set person = craft.entries.section('representatives').repId(myId).first() %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

and then output my info from there.